# GitHub pages displaying markdown as plain text

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I have a GitHub repository that uses GitHub pages. However, if you visit the [README page](https://mmk21hub.github.io/News/README.md), for example, you can quickly spot that it is showing up in the plain text, not markdown.

Have I forgotten to do something? The full repository is here: https://github.com/MMK21Hub/News

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the `README.html`, as it is blocking the `README.md` from being converted into HTML.

Answer (score -1):

you must enter the repository link, not the file link, when you enter a particular file it is always displayed in raw format

https://github.com/MMK21Hub/News/blob/master/README.md

Comment: That's to view it in the repository. I'm having problems with Github pages.